# Symfony2 create left join

Tags: php, mysql, symfony

I have two table

1)  cms

2)  cms_translations

**table 1) cms**

```
id
url
status
```

**table 2) cms_translations**

```
object_id
title
lang_id
```

**then what is left join query for display both table value in twig file?**

this is query done by me

```
    $q = $em->createQuery("SELECT c , d FROM Dashboard\CmsBundle\Entity\Cms c 
    JOIN c.translations d 
    WITH c.id = d.object AND c.status = 1
    GROUP BY c.sortOrder 
    ORDER BY c.sortOrder ASC "
    );
```

and this is code done by me for display in index.html.twing file

```
    {% for entity in enitity_cms %}
    <a href="{{ path('_cmsAboutUs' , { slug : entity.url }) }}" >{{ entity.Title }}</a>
    {% endfor %}
```

but not print in `{{ entity.Title }}`
then how to print cms_translations.title in twing file?

How do I print value in html file from second table?

Comment: `FROM FROM Dashboard\CmsBundle\Entity\Cms`? Really?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DQL:

```
SELECT c , d FROM Dashboard\CmsBundle\Entity\Cms c 
JOIN c.translations d WHERE c.status = 1
```

This ensures that the translations are loaded in the Cms object.

Then in the twig template:

```
{% for entity in entity_cms %}
  {% for translation in entity.translations %}
     <a href="{{ path('_cmsAboutUs' , { slug : entity.url }) }}" >{{ translation.Title }}</a>
  {% endfor %}    
{% endfor %}
```